# Does JSF provide input component where suggestion for textbox reappears after space?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, combobox, richfaces, autosuggest

I am looking for JSF component similar to auto suggestion or combo-box but with extended functionality that options in drop down suggestions reappears after user has clicked space. In other words, lets say combo-box has options "Option1", "Option 2", "Option 3", component should provide capability so that user can enter "Option 1 abc Option 2 xyz Option 3" by selecting "Option 1" first,  abc , hitting space should present drop down list again where user can select "Option 2".

I am not sure if something similar already exists. If anyone has idea, please let me know.

If you need more explanation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RichFaces provide a autocomplete component, is called  [RichFaces Autocomplete](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces4-demo/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&skin=blueSky).

In the link, you can see the second example, using ',' or ' ' you can select many values.

```
    <rich:autocomplete mode="cachedAjax" tokens=", " minChars="1"
        autofill="false" 
        autocompleteMethod="#{autocompleteBean.autocomplete}" />
```

In the [Showcase source](https://github.com/richfaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/richfaces/demo/autocomplete/AutocompleteBean.java), you can see the bean implementation

```
    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        if ((prefix == null) || (prefix.length() == 0)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                result.add(capitals.get(i).getState());
            }
        } else {
            Iterator<Capital> iterator = capitals.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Capital elem = ((Capital) iterator.next());
                if ((elem.getState() != null && elem.getState().toLowerCase().indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) == 0)
                        || "".equals(prefix)) {
                    result.add(elem.getState());
                }
            }
        }
```

Sorry for my bad english. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that I can use tokens with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tagit jquery plugin

[tagit jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it)

**Demo**: [tagit jquery plugin demo](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html)

Comment: Thanks. Behaviour is same but I was looking for JSF component.